# Second monitor freezes and shifts color after a couple minutes of use

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.04

Just today switched from windows 10 to ubuntu gnome 17.04 on my lenovo ideapad 310 (intel core i5-7200u , 8gb ddr4 ram , intel hd graphics 620) . After installing i connected my second monitor via HDMI and started using it as i did before installing ubuntu.

After around 1-2 hours of use , i was watching a youtube video on it and suddenly the video froze , and the color shifted , the youtube logo became blue and the facebook one became red , but the sound from the video kept going and when moving the mouse i could still see it moving on the second monitor , the chrome window was still working and i could interact with it but not really seeing what i am doing , mainly pausing the video and moving it back to the main monitor.

I tried searching online for people having similar problems and haven't really found anything. Can anyone help me diagnose the problem or had something similar ?

Comment: Have you rebooted or power-cycled everything? If I'm not mistaken, the Intel HD Graphics uses shared memory. You could go to http://memtest86.org and download the free memory test, and run it for at least one complete pass.